# django celery error "Apps aren't loaded yet" All recommended fixes I've tried has failed - I believe I have settings configured incorrectly somewhere

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

My goal is to use celery to use celery to automatically run script on my site each day. I followed the instructions for first steps with Django [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html). After I have all of my setting configured, I use `celery -A project worker --loglevel=info` and the server seems to start fine. When I attempt to import the tasks app it can't find the module, it says it doesn't exist,  but it works if I explicitly call folder.tasks. If I call `function.delay()` I get the following error:

> raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
>     django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

I am using `app.autodiscover_tasks()` in celery.py to locate `@shared_task` inside of my tasks module
I do a few searches and try adding a recommendation of using `Django-Q`. After I put it at the bottom of installed apps and attempt to `python manage.py migrate` celery, I get the same `AppRegistryNotReady` error as before but when I attempt to start celery. I tried adding `import django | django.setup()` in my settings.py as recommended by someone. How can I fix this issue? here is the traceback

```
C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Buylist_django>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 216, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\autodetector.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\questioner.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 22, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

C:\Users\Jup\PycharmProjects\Buylist_django>
```

here is my celery settings (celery 4.1):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery


# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery('project', broker='amqp://localhost//'))

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

And my Django setting.py:

```
import dj_database_url

import django
django.setup()

"""
Django settings for project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
#Read secret key from a file

SECRET_KEY = 'key'



# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
#DEBUG = True
DEBUG = bool( os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', True) )

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
                'shrouded-ocean-19461.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1',

]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_celery_results',
    'Buylist',
    'django_q',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates"),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

# The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# The URL tos use when referring to static files (where they will be served from)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Simplified static file serving.
# https://warehouse.python.org/project/whitenoise/
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

Your help would be much appreciated! Also, explain like I'm 5. Still pretty new to all of this. Thanks!

Comment: What's your celery version? What broker are you using? The `django.setup()` in the settings file is definitely not needed. Also, are you not setting a `CELERY_BROKER_URL`? (The latter is not your issue normally, I am just curious.) Could you be more specific on how you imported the tasks app of which you said that didn't work?

Comment: @GlenCodes Sorry, I'm using celery 4.1 and I'm using RabbitMQ. Th only place I had broker url defined was in celery.py. I removed it to test the code out. It was app = Celery('project', broker='amqp://localhost//'). I did not set CELERY_BROKER_URL. It was not present in the tutorial. I used @ shared_tasks in the tasks module and used app.autodiscover_tasks() in celery.py to locate it. the tasks.py is in a different folder –

Comment: might want to check this out.  seems to be related to you using regular django db for your result backend  https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/issues/20